# How can i Send my list From my controller to my DropDownList in the View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

i know it should look like this

```
@Html.DropDownList("yourDropName", listItems, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

but i can't figure it out how should i do it
in my controller i passed a list to it which was initialized in my model layer and in my View_Model i simply get it from model and pass it to my controller

this is in my model

```
    public List<int?> TeamId()
    {
        ListTeam = new List<int?>();
        using (var context = new EF_Model.DigikalaHREntities())
        {
            //var p = context.Members.Any(c => c.TeamId);
            var p = from c in context.Members
                    where c.TeamId.HasValue
                    select new { c.TeamId };
            return p.Select(m => m.TeamId).ToList();
        }
    }
```

i have 2 Classes in my view model first one is just entities with some Data Annotation and second one is the class which i get my methods from my Model 
so this is my View model layer(i didn't passed this one to my View)

```
     public List<int?> GetTeamId()
    {
        Ref_CRUD = new Models.CRUD.Member();
        return Ref_CRUD.TeamId();
    }
```

my controller

```
  #region [- Get -]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Ref_Member = new View_Model.Buisiness.Member();
        return View(Ref_Member.GetTeamId());
    }
```

this is my View

```
@model DigikalaHR.View_Model.Entitys.Member
 . 
 .
 .
 .
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TeamId, "TeamId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">       
 //don't know how to use one of These  two lines and which one i should use 
            @*@Html.DropDownList("TeamId",new SelectList(enum.(typeof())),htmlAttributes: new {@class="form-control" })*@
           @*@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TeamId,new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(id))),"GetTeamId")*@
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TeamId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can i Send my list From my controller to my DropDownList in the View?

Comment: You should use your view model strongly typed to your view, instead of the entity model. The view model will have properties needed for the view, including the collection needed for building the SELECT element options.

Comment: You have business and data access logic in your models? From where did you get that terrible idea? ViewModels and Entities are supposed to be POCOs

Comment: And what specifically you want to show in the dropdown ? the TeamId ? and you want to get those Ids from Member table ? Does not sound correct to me

Comment: What does this return: `Ref_Member.GetTeamId()`? Whatever you pass to the `View` method becomes your `Model`. I think you are passing a `List<int>`, no?

Comment: @Shyju yes there is a table called member and then i want to let the user to select one of those

Comment: @CodingYoshi a list of teamid

Comment: One of what ? You want to select TeamId from the member table ?

Comment: @Shyju yes that's true

Comment: What is the type of `TeamId` column or property ?

Comment: @Shyju in a Drop Down List of course

Comment: @Shyju int and nullable

Comment: And you do not want the user to select a TeamName  ? Is there a team table which has the TeamId and TeamName ?

Comment: A dirty way would be: `ViewBag.TeamIds = Ref_Member.GetTeamId()` and in your view: `new SelectList(ViewBag.TeamIds`. Better if you use a view model.

Comment: @Shyju yes it's a foreign key and i want them to select only teams id

Comment: @CodingYoshi dedicate one class in my view model just for filling that list?

Comment: No. Create one class that has everything to satisfy your view's needs. Then create an instance of that class and populate it in your controller (make it ready). Then pass that to your `View` method. Then change the `@model` to the type of whatever you passed into `View` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing things up here. Your view models should be models specific to the view and those are simply dumb POCO classes for data tranfer. No business logic or those has no idea about what your data access technology / entity classes are. Do not mix view models with entity classes.

So in your case, if your view is to create a member, you should have a view model with properties which are absolutely needed in the view (for input elements)

```
public class CreateMemberVm
{
   public string FirstName { set;get;}
   public int? SelectedTeamId { set;get;}
   public List<SelectListItem> Teams { set;get;}
   // Add other properties as needed by the view. 
}
```

Add other properties to your view model as needed by the view. There is no reason to blindly add all the properties from your entity class to your view models.

Now in your GET action, you initialize an object of this view model, popualte the `Teams` property with a list of `SelectListItem` objects (we will use this in the view to build the SELECT element options) and send the object to the vieww

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   var vm = new CreateMemeberVm();
   vm.Teams = GetTeamItems();
   return View(vm);
}
public List<SelectListItem> GetTeamItems()
{
    using (var db = new EF_Model.DigikalaHREntities())
    {
        return db.Teams
                 .Select(a=>new SelectListItem { 
                                                 Value=a.TeamId.ToString(),
                                                 Text=a.TeamName
                                               })
                  .ToList();
    }
}
```

Now in your view, which should be strongly typed to our view model, you can use the `DropDownListFor` helper method to render the SELECT element.

```
@model CreateMemberVm
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.LabelFor(a=>a.FirstName)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.FirstName)

   @Html.LabelFor(a=>a.SelectedTeamId)
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedTeamId, Model.Teams, "Select team")
   <input type="submit" />
}
```

You can use the same view model class as the parameter of your HttpPost action method and now when user submits the form after filling the form, the `SelectedTeamId` property and the `FirstName` property will be populated from the form data and you can use those to save to your table

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateMemeberVm model)
{
  // check model.FirstName and model.SelectedId
  // to do : Save as needed
  // to do : return something
}
```

If you want to preselect an item in your view (for the case of edit member use case), all you have to do is, set the `SelectedTeamId` property of your view model to whatever you have in your db

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
   var m = db.Members.Find(id);
   var vm = new CreateMemeberVm() { FirstName = m.FirstName, SelectedTeamId=m.TeamId};
   vm.Teams = GetTeamItems();
   return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: thank's a lot,just out of curiosity what should i do, if i wanted to use team's Names instead of IDs?

Comment: The code i have in the answer is querying the Teams table and use TeamName and TeamId

Comment: got an error i think it doesn't know `SelectLIstItem` ==>      **The type or namespace name 'SelectListItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: Where are you getting that error ? The code i shared does not have any such conversion!

Comment: it needed a name space

Comment: Add a `using System.Web.Mvc;` to the top of the class.

Comment: have no idea of what happened,can you explain what you did in my controller? or is there a document that i can read ?

Comment: Are you not able to follow the explanation i have in the answer ? Which specific part are you not able to follow

Comment: everything was crystal clear just wanted to know more about it