# Should i have a class for my drop down list?

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, viewmodel

I'm using a drop down list and i have a class in my view model proppertis looked like this

```
       [DisplayName("شماره تیم")]
    public List<int ?> TeamId { get; set; }
```

but i changed it to so i can use DropDownList

```
       [DisplayName("شماره تیم")]
    public List<SelectListItem> TeamId { get; set; }
```

[here you can find everything about my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48597982/how-can-i-send-my-list-from-my-controller-to-my-dropdownlist-in-the-view)

should i use different classes in my view model for each View?

Comment: As the name suggests, view models are specific to views. So add only those properties needed for your view, to your view model class definition. You can still use inheritance (have a base view model and other specific view models derive form it). But make sure you are not mixing your entity model with your view models.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to have a list of items, and each item contains a value and corresponding text to display, then sure, having a class to represent that makes perfect sense.

I'll only split one hair, and this may be a tiny split hair.

```
public List<SelectListItem> TeamId { get; set; }
```

The name of the class - `SelectListItem` - suggests that your view model is "telling" your view how to represent this data, using a `select` control. But the job of the view model is just to pass data, not to determine how it should be rendered. Perhaps the same data could also be rendered using radio buttons.

Like I said, that's some major hair-splitting. Other than that, using a class that way makes perfect sense. That can help you to create reusable partial views that render those classes as `select` elements or radio button groups.